# Elementary question about real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and let $x \in [a,b]$. Put

$$ F(x) = \int_{[a,x]} \chi_A dm $$

Then of course we know that $F $ is differentiable for almost all $x \in [a.b]$ and 
$$ F'(x) = 1  \; \; \text{for almost all } x \in [a,b] \cap A $$

Can someone explain to me why does it follow that $F'(x) = 1 $ implies that there exists $\epsilon$ and $\delta >0$ such that

$$ 1 \geq \frac{ m( [x , x +h] \cap A )}{h} > 1 - \epsilon \; \; for\; \; 0 < h < \delta$$

and

$$ 1 \geq \frac{ m( [x , x +k] \cap A )}{k} > 1 - \epsilon \; \; for \; \; 0 < k < \delta$$

Comment: If $A=\emptyset$, then $F' = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(x+h)-F(x)=\int_{[x,x+h]}\chi_{A}dm=m([x,x+h]\cap A)$$

Comment: How does this answer the question? If the set $A$ has measure zero, then $F(x+h)-F(x) = 0$, and there is no way it can satisfy the condition above?

Answer (score -1):

This is not true. If $A$ is the Cantor set, then $F=0$ and so $F'=0$ everywhere.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?