# Why is the following true?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

Can someone please explain to me the last part? Why does it follow? I am having a hard time seeing why.

Thanks.

PS: $| \cdot | $ is Lebesgue measure. $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable set.

Comment: downvoter: What is wrong with this question? please, explain.

Comment: i don't downvote, but it would be helpful if you stated what the set $A$ is. without that information the question is difficult to interpret

Comment: ok just edited.

Comment: This is a duplicate of question you asked a short while ago (except in the other question you omitted pertinent information). http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597855/elementary-question-about-real-analysis/597879#597879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the intersection of $[x-k,x] \cap A$ and $[x,x+h] \cap A$ has measure zero, you have:
$$
\mid [x-k,x+h]\cap A \mid = \mid [x-k,x]\cap A \mid + \mid[x,x+h]\cap A \mid
$$
you have also:
$$
k \ge \mid[x-k,x]\cap A\mid \gt k(1-\epsilon) \\
h \ge \mid [x, x+h]\cap A \mid \gt h(1-\epsilon)
$$
adding the inequalities:
$$
k+h \ge \mid[x-k,x]\cap A\mid + \mid [x, x+h]\cap A \mid \gt (k+h)(1-\epsilon)
$$
i.e.
$$
k+h \ge \mid[x-k,x+h]\cap A\mid \gt (k+h)(1-\epsilon)
$$
dividing through by the positive quantity $h+k$ gives the required conclusion

Answer (score 2):

The fraction you ask about (with $h+k$ in the denominator) is a weighted average of the corresponding fractions in the preceding formulas (i) and (ii), the weights being $h/(h+k)$ and $k/(h+k)$.  So all you need is that, if two numbers are in an interval (in this case the interval $(1-\epsilon,1]$), then any weighted average of those two numbers, being between the two numbers, is also in that interval.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is using the fact that if $B$ and $D$ are positive, and if $A/B < z$ and $C/D < z$, then

$\frac{A+C}{B+D} < z$

That on its own isn't very hard to show:

Since $\frac AB < z$ and $B>0$, $A < Bz$.

Since $\frac CD < z$, and $D>0$, $C < Dz$.

Then $A + C < Bz + Dz = (B+D)z$, and $\frac{A+C}{B+D} < z$ (note $B+D>0$).

More generally, $(A+C)/(B+D)$ is always between $A/B$ and $C/D$ on the real number line, or all three expressions could be equal.

Comment: can you show why this result is true? thanks

Comment: Note: $A,B,C,D$ are positive here.

Comment: Added a short proof.